# Alternative to email notification system?

Tags: email, notifications

Instead of having an email on every comment on a blog post I've wrote, I'm looking for a visual notification on wordpress itself, an "inbox" if you get what I mean.

Does that exist?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be visible by default on your WP admin dashboard under "recent comments". is there something else you're looking for it to do?

Comment: Hi Norcross, basically I want something in the template itself, as I restricted wp-admin access. People are still allowed to post using a custom form using wp_insert :)

Comment: I see. So if I'm reading this right, you want something visually on the front-end of the site?You could create a page template that has the site-wide recent comments.

Comment: Hi Norcross, it wouldn't be site wide, but only an "inbox" for the comments on the author's own post

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not sure if that is something that exists. That's sort of what the admin dashboard is intended for :)